# Create a nested JSON Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I´d like to create a JSON-Object for a Google API-Request. Only *content* is needed to change. My solution gives me an invalid JSON-Format and is more a hack. Is there an easier way to do this? Thank your for your hints.

The necessary format look like this:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "/9j/7QBEUGhvdG9zaG9...base64-encoded-image-content...fXNWzvDEeYxxxzj/Coa6Bax//Z"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JS**

```
var cvs = cvs.substring('data:image/png;base64,'.length);

var json1 = '{"requests":[{  "image":{    "content":"'
var json2 = '"},  "features": [{"type":"DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"}]    } ]}'

var entireJson = json1 + cvs + json2;
var ocrImage = JSON.stringify(entireJson);
```

Comment: your Jsons are not formatted correctly.

Comment: If it is a string, why would you stringify it?!

Comment: I think he meant to JSON.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done in your example is initializing a Javascript Object.

`JSON.parse(object_string);` is not necessary. You may initialize it directly:

```js
var ocrImage = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "/9j/7QBEUGhvdG9zaG9...base64-encoded-image-content...fXNWzvDEeYxxxzj/Coa6Bax//Z"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(ocrImage)
```